# KS test: R vs Python

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics

I get different values of KS test in R and Python.

> input_test = [2457.145, 878.081, 855.118, 1157.135, 1099.82, 880.0,
> 1399.0339999999999]

**R code:**

```
> parameters
 meanlog    sdlog 
9.621626 2.220691 

H <- 846.6572

truncgof::ks.test(input_test, 'plnorm', parameters, H=H, sim=50)
```

**R output:**

```
data:  input_test
KS = 2.3246, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

treshold = 846.6572, simulations: 50
```

**Python code:**

```
import scipy.stats as st
p = [ 2.22096211e+00, 1.50686480e+04]
ks = st.kstest(input_test, st.lognorm.cdf, args=([p[0], 0, p[1])]), N=50, alternative='two-sided')
```

**Python output:**

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.7929187086107005, pvalue=3.34390068700874e-05)
```

Does anybody know how to get the same results (or similar)? Is it possible to set a threshold value in Python (H in R)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
It uses package `truncdist` to create a truncated log-normal distribution function and then runs the KS test with base R `ks.test`. The results are similar but not exactly the same as you Python result.

```
library(truncdist)

ptrunclnorm <- function(x, H, ...){
  truncdist::ptrunc(x, spec = "lnorm", a = H, b = Inf, ...)
}

input_test = c(2457.145, 878.081, 855.118, 1157.135, 1099.82, 880.0, 1399.0339999999999)
H <- 846.6572
meanlog <- 9.621626 
sdlog <- 2.220691

parameters <- c(meanlog, sdlog)

set.seed(2020)
truncgof::ks.test(input_test, 'plnorm', parameters, H=H, sim=50)

ks.test(input_test, "ptrunclnorm", H = H, meanlog = meanlog, sdlog = sdlog)
#
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  input_test
#D = 0.8786, p-value = 7.771e-07
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

---

Package `EnvStats` has functions for the truncated log-normal distribution and therefore to define it is not needed.

```
library(EnvStats)

ks.test(input_test, "plnormTrunc", 
        meanlog = meanlog, sdlog = sdlog, 
        min = H, max = Inf)
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: So does Python truncate dataset when computing KS? Is it possible to get similar results in Python as R results

Comment: @ruan No, that's not the truncated lognormal distribution Python is passing to `scipy.stats.kstest`.

Comment: @ruanNo, you are not understanding what I wrote. Python does **not** use the truncated distribution, that R code does.